# How to define a field in spring-roo which appears on the page but doesn't get persisted

Tags: java, spring, spring-roo

Q1> In spring-roo how can I define a field that I want to appear on the page but doesn't get persisted in the DB.

For e.g: If I have a confirm-password field that I want to appear on the page so that I can validation the password but don't want to persist it.

Q2> Is there a way to define a password field directly form roo shell.

Answer (score 1):

Q1:
Mark the field with @Transient. This is really a JPA question more than a Roo question.

Q2:
You can define the field in the roo shell, but I don't believe there is a transient option in the Roo shell. You have to Mark the field with the @Transient option after you generate it with the roo shell.

BTW Roo rocks.

Comment: There is a way to define transient field through roo shell it attaches a transient key word, which skips the creation of field on the page too. 

I know what transient annotation does, well i'll try to explicitly place transient annotation and see if roo removes the field from the page or not.

Comment: field string --fieldName password --transient

Comment: the roo command using "--transient" does not add the @Transient annotation, it marks the field with the transient keyword. That will ensure its not serialized if you were trying to store the class to disk, but has nothing to do with JPA's persistence to the database